# '<=' and '>=' operators do not work

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

To check if the the installer is installed, I did:

```
installer status |grep Version| cut -c12-13
```

The ouput [sic] says:

```
installer not found
```

But if it were installed, it would say `11` or `10` (any numeric). If the output is `<=10 || >=11`, then it would say `not installed`, and would proceed with the installation. In the library, it gives:

```
def get_installer_linux_version
  begin
    cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('installer status |grep Version| cut -c12-13')
    cmd.run_command
  rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
    return '0.0'
  end
  return 'Version 10' if cmd.stdout.include? '10'  
  return 'Version 11' if cmd.stdout.include? '11'
end
```

In the install recipe is:

```
if get_installer_linux_version.to_i <= 10 || get_installer_linux_version.to_i >= 11 
  log  'installer is installed'
else
  log 'installer is not installed so procceding with the installation'
```

Comment: Seriously? Stating that a fundamental function of the language is broken that would cause nearly all code written not to work instead of accepting that perhaps your own code is flawed? What values are `get_installer_linux_version.to_i` returning?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not to mention you are comparing the string `"version XX"`  (or `nil`) to a numeric.

Comment: What is `ouput`?

Comment: get_installer_linux_version.to_i returns 
bash: installer: command not found

Comment: What's that have to do with `<=` and `>=` operators not working?

Comment: my problem is it says 'installer is installed'
so it does not procced with further installation

Comment: Read my answer below. Every single result that you return is going to evaluate to `0`, which is in fact `<= 10`, and gives that output.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that perhaps you have the definition of `<` and `>` backwards in how you think they work. Do you expect version to be between 10 and 11, or anything other than a version between 10 and 11?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous things in your code that could be considered flawed, but for the sake of your question, I will focus on that.

`get_installer_linux_version` returns a few possible values. Either the string `"version 10"`,  `"version 11"`, `"0.0"`, or `nil`.  You call this function, then call to `to_i` on it.

Maybe this will help illistrate it:

```
"version 10".to_i
#=> 0
```

I am going to guess that is not the intended behavior. No matter what happens in your `get_installer_linux_version`, the returned string will always be `0` after you call `to_i` on it. You then make condition that `<= 10`, which `0` is still less than `10`, and it logs `"installer is installed"`.

I would also venture to guess that using `include? 'XX'` is going to end up causing you problems when dealing with version numbers, but that is another question.

To further illustrate, let me write your code as it will always, always, always be as you have it written, and see if something looks off:

```
if 0 <= 10 || 0 >= 11 
  log  'installer is installed'
else
  log 'installer is not installed so procceding with the installation'
```

What do you expect the result to be?? Although `0` is not ever going to be greater than 11, it will always be less than `10`, so your result is always the same.

Just going to put this here, as it may be relevant the more I look at your sample.

- `>=`

  > Checks if the value of left operand is greater than or equal to the
  >   value of right operand, if yes then condition becomes true.
- `<=`

  > Checks if the value of left operand is less than or equal to the value
  >   of right operand, if yes then condition becomes true.

Comment: my problem is it says 'installer is installed'
so it does not proceed with further installation

Comment: Yes, as your code is always going to do as I explained. `0` is always going be less than `10`, so why wouldn't it? Are you sure you didn't intend `>= 10` instead of `<= 10`? Not that it will make much difference, as no matter what, until you fix that method, there is no point in even using it.

Comment: incase the installer is installed 
the output would say 
Version = 10 xxx
I have tried once with if get_installer_linux_version == 10 
so that time it worked , only when <= and >= started giving the problem

Comment: That is not even a theoretical possibility with the exact code that you have posted. Your `return` statements would have to read `return '10' if cmd.stdout.include? 'Version 10'` for that to happen, which they are backwards, so I am going to have to say that you are mistaken the exact code you have with `==` instead of `<=` works.

Comment: if the output contains 10 then it would say 'Version 10' so long , now
 there is a possibility that if its 13 or 8 it should work that is proceed with the installation

Comment: As I already stated, IT WILL NEVER EVALUATE HOW YOU THINK IT DOES. The string `"Version 10"`, `"Version 9343.2342342"`, `"Version 2"`, and every number in the world is always going to be `0` after calling `to_i` on it. That is what you are doing, and then comparing `0` with condition that is less than or equal to `10`, which it it is. Always going to be. Not gonna change. How do you think that works? Please take time to read my answer and study your code closer.

Comment: yes i understand, on removing to_i i get 
undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass 
But I do not how to solve the issue

Comment: Because `cmd.stdout.include?` does not return `true` for `'10'` or `'11'`, so the method returns `nil`.

Comment: Yes correct , if its nil then its not 10 or 11 which means its should go to the else block 
saying the installer is not installed and procced with te installation 
When i used to check intially get_installer_linux_version == 10 
and if its nill it did go to else saying its not installed  why not now?

Comment: NO! It returns `nil` to the caller method, which then calls `to_i` on it.  `nil.to_i` equals `0`. You then compare that to see if it is less than or equal to `10`, which it is, so it outputs `"installer is installed"`  I will say yet again `get_installer_linux_version` will ALWAYS 100% of the time return a value that becomes `0` after calling `to_i` on it. YOU NEED TO FIX THAT.

Comment: Correct , so it means i have no other means if it includes version 13 or 14 if thats a case in the future 
But only hardcode the value to version to ==10

Comment: There are many better and different ways, far more efficient, and do not require hard-coding anything, but this a Q&A site, not teach how to code site. This will have to be something you discover as you learn the language.